# Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm" in qt5 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-18.04

Firstly, I find some similar questions here, and have tried some answers, but that don't work.

**My environment**

> Ubuntu 18.04
>
> Nvidia + cuda-10.1 + cudnn-7.6.5
>
> QT 5.14.1 64 bits

**Error message**

> Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm"

**My question**

1. Why does this error happen after I have installed dependencies with "sudo apt install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev" ?
2. Why does qt find *GL/gl.h* in */usr/include/libdrm* ?
   Actually I find *GL* folder within *usr/include*, but not within */usr/include/libdrm*
3. How to fix that problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and it turned out I was doing

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QtQml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS} ${QtQml_DEFINITIONS} ${${Qt5Quick_DEFINITIONS}})
```

before setting the project

```
project(MyProject)
```

within the `CMakeLists.txt` and that was causing the whole problem.